# Можно ли указать номер порта на котором будет запущен allure report?

Tags: allure

При генерации Allure отчетов используя [Allure Commandline](http://wiki.qatools.ru/display/AL/Allure+Commandline) при выполении команды:

$ allure report open

Запускается веб-сервер на локальном хосте при этом каждый разу указывается рандомный номер порта. Можно ли указать желаемый номер порта но котором необходимо запускать веб-сервер с отчетами?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Судя по [коду](https://github.com/allure-framework/allure1/blob/master/allure-commandline/src/main/java/ru/yandex/qatools/allure/command/ReportOpen.java#L28) порт можно указать явно:

```
@Option(name = {"-p", "--port"}, type = OptionType.COMMAND,
        description = "This port will be used to start web server for the report")
```